Webhook checks history Github
I'm trying to preserve webhook Checks in Github.
When a Check is run for a pull request, after that PR is merged, or if the commit is amended, we lose track of previous runs for that PR.
Here is an example after the PR is merged:

It doesn't show any Details for those checks. In case of amended commits, the latest run overwrite previous runs.
Does anyone know a workaround for that?
